# NullPointerException: displaying video from a list

Tags: android, list, video, hyperlink

Hi I'm trying to display a video from a list and I keep getting the null pointer exception any ideas why?

This is my code:

```
    public class HallList extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.lecturehalls ,R.layout.list_item));



        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                            if (position == 0)
                {   video(position);

                }
                else if(position == 1)
                { 
                    video(position);


            }
        }
        });
    }

        private void video(int position){



                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        if (position == 0){

            //example path
            String path0="http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";



            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

            videoView.setVideoPath(path0);

            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

            videoView.requestFocus();

            videoView.start();

            mediaController.show(); }

           else if( ........ ){...}

}

   }
```

I'm not sure of my way of doing it right..If there's an easier way to do it could you please help me with it..I saw a tutorial displaying web links from a list..I want to create it the same way but don't seem to get how its done with list of video links?
this is the tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-listview/
Thanx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which xml file you define your VideoView? Without `setContentView()` your are defining your videoView

(Without seeing your error log I am guessing) I think this line cause **nullPointerException,**

```
   VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
```

You have to define VIideoView in your xml file and set that xml file as a `setContentView(main.xml)`

also put this line after setContentView() in onCreate() of your activity..

Comment: I have a videoview.xml which I defined the videoview there I added the contentview but now there's an error: your content should have a ListView?

Comment: Yes, put a listview inside that videoview.xml file, and extend your activity as a simple Activity instead of ListActivity. Then define listview in activity and set the adapter on that.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in a debugger, then look at the stack trace to see where the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the setContentView in the code. and you are getting the getListView in the OnCreate method which will result in to null pointer exception.

Comment: I added the setContentView like you said which has the videoview..but it gives me error :your content should have a ListView..I have done this without the set content view if I remove the video function and create a separate class VideoView it works fine ..but like this it will be for each video I have to create a separate class and I dont want it like that.